# Precedence and association in OCaml; unexpected result when calculating Catalan numbers

Tags: ocaml

Unexpected behavior in simple function to calculate the n*th* Catalan number.

```
let rec catalan x =
    match x with
        0 -> 1
        | n -> catalan(n - 1) * 2 * (2 * n - 1) / (n + 1)
```

This gives the expected answers (*e.g.*, catalan 3 -> 5).

However,

```
let rec catalan2 x =
    match x with
        0 -> 1
        | n -> (2 * (2 * n - 1) / (n + 1)) * catalan2(n - 1)
```

gives unexpected (incorrect) answer (*e.g.*, catalan 3 -> 4).

It seems to me that these should be semantically identical. Is there something about precedence of operators in OCaml that I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* an identity for integer operations:

```
(a * b) / c = (b / c) * a
```

For example:

```
(2 * 5) / 3 =? (5 / 3) * 2
10 / 3 =? 1 * 2
3 =? 2
```

The integer division operation `/` is not the same as the usual mathematical division (for real numbers).

**Update**

You have this:

```
catalan(n - 1) * 2 * (2 * n - 1) / (n + 1)
```

You claim it should be identical to this:

```
(2 * (2 * n - 1) / (n + 1)) * catalan (n - 1)
```

Let's give names to the subexpressions. Then you have this:

```
a * b * c / d
```

You say it should be identical to this:

```
(b * c / d) * a
```

This is not the case. It's a slightly more complicated version of what I showed above.

Comment: But `2 * (2 * n - 1) / (n + 1)` is exactly the same expression in both instances above. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're leaving out the recursive call to catalan.